# Database cleaner removes data when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, database-cleaner

Has anyone ran into problem like that?

I have a controller, which triggers mailer delivery:

```
  def create
    create! do |success, failure|
      success.js do
        CandidateMailer.donation_notification(current_candidate).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

And I got that mailer:

```
  def donation_notification(candidate)
    puts Candidate.count  # note: during test - count of candidates is 0
    @candidate = candidate
    email_with_name = "#{@candidate.profile.name} <#{@candidate.email}>"
    mail(to: email_with_name, subject: 'New Donation Received!')
  end
```

I don't understand why database cleaner removes all data before test is actually finished.

It's a JS test (with Webkit) if that matters at all.

Here's my config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = [:truncation, { pre_count: true }]
    end

    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the rspec example as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the [code](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/b254ce57bdeea927e514a486aedc2ac97199324b/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb), both [clean](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/b254ce57bdeea927e514a486aedc2ac97199324b/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb#L86) and [clean_with](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/b254ce57bdeea927e514a486aedc2ac97199324b/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb) actually delegate to `strategy.clean`, which means they both actively clean.

When you call

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end
```

It cleans your database before the tests begin.

In a test situation, this might be OK, if you seed your test data at the beginning of the suite (or before each test).